# Append Data in Custom list arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom list with image arrayadapter.I need to add some new data into that list arrayadapter.I tried to add data by

```
your_array_list.add("foo");
your_array_list.add("bar");
```

but this is not working help me to add data to list view

Here is my adapter class

```
public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
        }



        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Here is my activity code

```
applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        ;
        ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If first initialization:

```
applist.add("foo");
ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
```

later on if you are willing to add data:

```
applist.add("foo");
listadaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

From your code i see that as a parameter of your adapter you are givin a list of objects (`List<ApplicationInfo>`),so instead of adding string `applist.add("foo")` you need to add an `ApplicationInfo` object something like:

```
ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> yourList = new ArryList<>();
yourList.add(applist);
```

Comment: I am getting error notice "The method add(ApplicationInfo) in the type List<ApplicationInfo> is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: That error is shown because you have initialized a list of ApplicationInfo objects and trying to add a string to that list. Change `List<ApplicationInfo>` to `List<String>`

or instead of `applist.add("foo");` use `applist.add(new ApplicationInfo());`

Comment: please give me sample code. can u please edit your answer

Comment: @vibinreji edited. Hope it helps. But if you clarify your question to tell on  what you are trying to achieve maybe we can help you on code refactoring too

Comment: thanks...but i dont want add existing package detail.i need to add dummy packages.for example my device dont have twitter app but need add it manually

Comment: if so you have to change the parameter of your adapter `public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<string> appsList)`
and add dummy data: `ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArryList<>();
yourList.add("dummy.package.name");`